# Using Kendo Grid - onclick requires an extra click to call a jquery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have 7 columns (using html Kendo Grid), and the ID column is a PK of each row and its visible(false).
So..  When you click on any "Name" data, it grabs a PK(the ID that is invisible) of the row you selected, and a modal screen will pop up so you can see more detailed information.

Currently, it is working as expected, however, when the page loads for the first time, I have to double click it to make the modal screen display. Once the modal screen displays, after that, onclick event works as intended.

But I just noticed that when I hit the F12 key to see the log, the number of click increments(like... x2 x3 etc.) everytime onclick event calls.

When I Debug, it hits the debug point in my code but disappears right away so its really hard for me to investigate.

Thank you for your help.

------Column that has the onclick event--------

```
Columns(columns => {columns.Bound(o => o.SiteID).Visible(false); 
columns.Bound(o => o.Name).Title("Your Name").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new {title = "Name(s)"}).ClientTemplate("<a class='nameLink' onclick=\"EditSite(#:SiteID#);\" style='cursor:pointer;' SiteID=\'#=SiteID#\'>#=Name#</a>");
```

----Jquery onclick event ------

```
function EditSite(SiteID) {
debugger;
$('.nameLink').on('click', function () {

    $('#popUpEdit').dialog({
        width: 1000,
        height: 920,
        show: 'fadein',
        hide: 'fadeout',
        buttons: { "Close": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
        close: function () {
            $("#popUpEdit input").val("");
            $('#popUpEdit input').prop('checked', false);
            $('#statusMessage').html("");
        }
    });
    NameDetails(SiteID);
});
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding an onClick function every time the EditSite function is called. Try using .off() to unbind any existing handlers.

```
$('.nameLink').off().on('click', function () { }
```

Also try wrapping your function so you can pass your SiteID parameter.

(not sure the proper syntax for this)

```
onclick="EditSite(#:SiteID#)"
```

Wrapping the function

```
function EditSite(SiteID) {
  return function() {
      $('#popUpEdit').dialog({
        width: 1000,
        height: 920,
        show: 'fadein',
        hide: 'fadeout',
        buttons: { "Close": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
        close: function () {
            $("#popUpEdit input").val("");
            $('#popUpEdit input').prop('checked', false);
            $('#statusMessage').html("");
        }
      });
      NameDetails(SiteID);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but the onclick event doesn't work if I add .off().

Comment: It might be because you are invoking the function when you specify  onclick=\"EditSite(#:SiteID#);\". Try only passing the function without invocation. If you want to have the handler take your SiteID parameter, wrap the function. I will edit the post above.

Comment: When you are using Kendo grid, I have to use the "\" after onclick.. otherwise it won't work. Right now it is passing the parameter(SiteID) just fine. I'm not really sure other ways to pass the params.

Comment: But I agree that it's binding everytime the popup function calls.. ;(

Comment: Did you try the new code I edited? That might fix the issue

Comment: Yeah, I still have to double click it.

Comment: So yeah, I actually fixed this issue this morning. It was actually really a silly mistake. This was happening because basically I had 2 onclick events. In that anchor tag, I already have onclick=\"EditSite(#:SiteID#);\". And also, in my jquery EditSite method, I have another $('.nameLink').on('click', function (). Since I already declared onclick for the first time, I don't really have to have another 'click' in my jquery method.

Comment: So now its working as intended. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, because your edited function gave me the idea.

Comment: Hi I'm having the same problem, I call the function from a kendo grid, when the grid size increases and there appears a scroll bar, scrolling down to that element and then clicking into it does not work for the first time. Any idea regarding this?